Are gcc and g++ now distinct executables?
According to comments and accepted answers linked below, gcc and g++ are the same executable. Because they are the same, the value of argv[0] will determine behavior, whether the argument is "gcc" or "g++".
See accepted answer
Some comments here seem to confirm but some seem like they might hint at separate executables
However, I see different inode numbers (and file sizes) for the two.
owner@fedora:~/code/make_test$ ls -ilh /usr/bin/gcc
1584205 -rwxr-xr-x. 3 root root 1020K May 21 17:00 /usr/bin/gcc
owner@fedora:~/code/make_test$ ls -ilh /usr/bin/g++
1584212 -rwxr-xr-x. 4 root root 1.0M May 21 17:00 /usr/bin/g++

I happened to observe the following when compiling a hello_world.cpp program with the -v flag:
gcc version 13.3.1 20240522 (Red Hat 13.3.1-1) (GCC)
I considered the possibility that Red Hat implemented their own gcc with their own idioms, but it does not appear that my gcc installation comes from any nonstandard repo. I'm using Fedora 39 and did not expect to see Red Hat content in my OS (although I don't see why RH content could not have been merged into an upstream distro at some point).
owner@fedora:~/code/make_test$ dnf repolist
repo id                                                                                                       repo name
fedora                                                                                                        Fedora 39 - x86_64
fedora-cisco-openh264                                                                                         Fedora 39 openh264 (From Cisco) - x86_64
opera                                                                                                         Opera packages
rpmfusion-free                                                                                                RPM Fusion for Fedora 39 - Free
rpmfusion-free-updates                                                                                        RPM Fusion for Fedora 39 - Free - Updates
rpmfusion-nonfree                                                                                             RPM Fusion for Fedora 39 - Nonfree
rpmfusion-nonfree-updates                                                                                     RPM Fusion for Fedora 39 - Nonfree - Updates
updates                                                                                                       Fedora 39 - x86_64 - Updates

owner@fedora:~/code/make_test$ dnf whatprovides gcc
Last metadata expiration check: 0:02:01 ago on Tue 30 Jul 2024 08:16:27 PM MST.
gcc-13.2.1-3.fc39.x86_64 : Various compilers (C, C++, Objective-C, ...)
Repo        : fedora
Matched from:
Provide    : gcc = 13.2.1-3.fc39

gcc-13.3.1-1.fc39.x86_64 : Various compilers (C, C++, Objective-C, ...)
Repo        : @System
Matched from:
Provide    : gcc = 13.3.1-1.fc39

gcc-13.3.1-1.fc39.x86_64 : Various compilers (C, C++, Objective-C, ...)
Repo        : updates
Matched from:
Provide    : gcc = 13.3.1-1.fc39

So, I believe I have the "official" gcc and I do not understand why gcc and g++ are not the same file. Are gcc and g++ now distinct executables, have they always been distinct, and if not when did they split? Or have I just been misinformed about them ever being the same?

Considering that g++ has been a separate package in Ubuntu for ages, and definitely separate binaries since at least 10.04, and the first post you link to is about macOS where we have Apple's shenanigans of linking gcc and g++ to clang, did it ever apply to anything other than Macs? Here's what I see in a Docker container of Ubuntu 10.04: ls -l /usr/bin/{gcc,g++}-4.4 -go -> -rwxr-xr-x 1 255104 Mar  9  2012 /usr/bin/g++-4.4 and -rwxr-xr-x 1 255192 Mar  9  2012 /usr/bin/gcc-4.4.

The Q&A you found specifically refers to macOS and clang, not the GNU Compiler Collection.
As far as I remember, GCC (not clang) has always shipped separate executables for gcc and g++. Early versions even shipped separate source archives for the C and C++ compilers. In some versions, g++ was a shell script calling gcc with additional options, but I’m not aware of it ever being a link to gcc.
(Regarding the presence of “Red Hat content” in Fedora, note that Fedora is sponsored by Red Hat.)

Just to add that GCC, which stands for GNU Compiler Collection, includes compilers for many languages, including Obj-C, Go, Modula-2, Ada, and so on. The list of languages for which to produce compilers for is specified when configuring the compilation of GCC itself from source by using --enable-languages. C and C++ are just two of the supported languages.
